# Setting Excel outline options using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

There is a table grouped using **xlsxwriter**, in which, due to the large number of rows, in order to collapse the group, you have to scroll the document [image].

**How can I put a collapse/expand button on the first row of a group using xlsxwriter?**

I grouped the rows using this command:
worksheet.set_row(row, None, None, {'level': 1})
However, I did not find a suitable parameter in the set_row function arguments to solve the problem

**Desired result**:

[image]

Comment: P.S. 
in excel this setting looks like [this](https://thespreadsheetguru.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Steps-to-Change-Settings-for-Outline-Groups-in-Excel.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XlsxWriter you can control this via the worksheet [`outline_settings()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#outline_settings) method. In particular set the `symbols_below` parameter to false.